# Variable Input/Output node using a new command

Tags: macros, nodes, node-connections

How can I create a variable input/output node using a new command as in the following picture[image: VriableSizeNode]

Say for example, I know that the node will have **n** inputs and **m** outputs, which I enter the name as an argument for the new command, and at the same time, use it easily to link a specific input to a specific output

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question.  Are you looking to draw this picture, draw a similar (generalized) picture, or set up some sort of macro interface described by this picture? (haven't had my coffee yet)

Comment: It's the macros I'm looking for. I have to use the same block several times but with different number of inputs and outputs